# Non-uniqueness of group structure for affine algebraic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-groups

We know that every abelian variety has a unique group structure, but in the affine case, is that every affine algebraic group has more than one (up to isomorphism) group structure?

Answer (score 3):

Since a the affine variety underlying a non-trivial affine group always has non-identity automorphisms with no fixed points, you can always conjugate its group structure by one of them to get a different group structure.

**Later.** As for the more precise question, the answer is also no. Take an algebraically closed field. The only non-complete connected algebraic groups of dimension one are the multiplicative and the additive groups, and they are non-isomorphic *as varieties*. It follows that each of them is an algebraic group in exactly one way up to isomorphism.

Comment: You probably wanted to know if there are several non-isomorphic group structures, though...

Comment: Yes, I mean distinct group structures up to isomorphism. I have amended my statement.

Comment: Thanks! Anyway, I still want to ask, what kinds of affine algebraic groups have the unique group structure? Is there any general results or some references?